# Memory leak in Swift structures - How to fix this?

Tags: ios, macos, memory-leaks, swift2, xcode7

I'm developing an application in Swift 2 (Xcode 7 beta 3) and I'm trying to use value types (structs and enums) where possible. According to Apple's documentation about memory management, working with value types should not cause any retain cycles and it should just work.

But today I encountered a huge amount of memory leaks in event handling code. I tracked it down and reduced the problem to the following minimal example.

Let's say there is a protocol `Item` which defines a single property `value`:

```
protocol Item {

    var value: String { get }

}
```

We then create a concrete struct which implements the `Item` protocol and adds an additional property `additionalValue`. Let's call the struct `FooItem`.

```
struct FooItem<T>: Item {

    let value: String
    let additionalValue: T

    init(value: String, additionalValue: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.additionalValue = additionalValue
    }

}
```

The third piece of the puzzle is another struct which wraps an item implementing the `Item` protocol. It's called `ItemWrapper`.

```
struct ItemWrapper {

    let item: Item

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
    }

}
```

If profiled in Instruments using the Memory Leaks configuration, a memory leak appears every time an `ItemWrapper` value is created with a `FooItem`.

```
let item = FooItem(value: "protocol value", additionalValue: "foo item value")  
let _ = ItemWrapper(item: item)
```

[image: Instruments screenshot 1]
[image: Instruments screenshot 2]

Here is the example **Xcode project** and the **Instruments file**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6ugxzxqggrv1xl/SwiftStructsMemoryLeak.zip?dl=0

The **whole code example** can be viewed in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/lukaskubanek/4e3f7657864103d79e3a

Here is the bug report: **rdar://21375421**

Is it a bug in the Swift compiler or am I doing anything wrong?

---

**EDIT 1**: As suggested in the comments, I reposted this question on the **Apple Dev Forum** in order to draw more attention from the Swift community and potentially from the developers of the language. Due to a migration of the dev forums during WWDC 2015 I had to post an updated question on the new forums. Here is the link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/9643

---

**EDIT 2**: The problem I originally posted in the example code seems to be resolved in **Swift 2.0**. Since it didn't solve the issues in my app I made another modification to the example code. Now the `FooItem`'s additional property has a generic type and `FooItem` is annotated with the type and thus a generic type. This is how I'm using it in my app and it still causes a memory leak, but this time when the `ItemWrapper` is initialized rather than when accessing the property.

---

**EDIT 3**: Fully updated the question to the modified problem which persists in Swift 2.0 and uploaded new example Xcode project.

Comment: What do you mean by elsewhere - in the code or for further resources about the topic on other websites?

Comment: The example is actually just those 3 entities and the code which calls them. See this Gist https://gist.github.com/lukaskubanek/4e3f7657864103d79e3a for the whole AppDelegate. Sorry for not mentioning it in the question.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue, but no idea what the hell is going on.. +1

Comment: Great to hear that it's not only me. So you do think that it's a bug? Should I write a radar? Maybe we'll get a new Swift version next week which might fix this issue...

Comment: Interesting that it only happens with the wrapper, and if you add more wrappers around the wrapper it doesn't get worse. It may be a bug. Might want to bring it up on the developer forums and see if people there think it's a bug. This is pretty interesting so it'll probably get attention quickly.

Comment: @BenKane Thanks for the hint! I reposted the question on the Swift dev forum. Let's see how it turns out.

Comment: @LukasKubanek Cool I will follow it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I haven't got a response from Apple neither on the dev forums nor in the bug tracker and I haven't found anything related to this issue in the release notes of the latest beta versions, it seems to be solved in the Swift compiler in **Xcode 7 beta 5**. (Maybe it also works in beta 4. The last version I've checked was beta 3.)

The demo project doesn't produce the memory leak anymore. The same is true for my app. Yay!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's a workaround, although I have no idea why it works.  I noticed that if you do this:

```
    let theItem = itemWrapper.item
    let value = theItem.value
```

...instead of this:

```
    let value = itemWrapper.item.value
```

...it doesn't generate the memory leak.

Comment: I found this workaround, too. The problem is that this works just for properties. In my real code I have also methods defined in the protocol and they generate memory leaks as well. So I had to write functions wrapping all the concrete types (like `FooItem` etc.) and that's no fun.

Comment: Yeah.  My guess is it's just a bug in the Swift compiler that will (hopefully) eventually get fixed, and the "solution" is to just post a radar and wait for Apple to address it.  (There *is* a compiler directive that lets you turn on "Swift Optimizations" which will give you a different build.  You might try turning that on and seeing if that fixes it.  But be warned that also introduces some known problems, so it might be a tradeoff.)

Comment: OK, I'll wait for today's announcements (WWDC) and file a radar if this bug won't be fixed in the new Swift version.

Comment: A year later I had the same situation. This workaround is what solved my memory leak issue. The problem is that I too don't understand why this solution works. If it is a bug in swift I think it would be a very common one and it should have been addressed by now...